# Subset and subsample netCDF data using panoply

Tags: netcdf

I can plot a (very large) cube of temperature data (x,y, time) in panoply,
and zoom in on the region of study, but is there a way to actually
subset this region and save it to a new nc file?
Same for the time axis, is it possible to subset a given period of time and
even subsample (eg. 1 every 10 observations) it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't subset and extract data using Panoply.

A tool such as NCO (netCDF Operators) or CDO (Climate Data Operators) will probably do it, but there will be a learning curve.

[Charlie Zender](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2573697/charlie-zender) here on Stack could say much more.